# Can I define my own subclass of java.util.List?

Tags: java, list

Can I define my own list in Java?

I have my own list-type class that is very similar to a `LinkedList`, called `PersonList`. 
In another program, I'm using a `Comparator`, so I need to have a `List()` object as the parameter.

Is it possible to make the following statement, if I make changes in my code?

```
List list1= new PersonList();
```

`PersonList` doesn't extend or import anything.

Comment: Yes. Change `PersonList` to implement `java.util.List`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks so much! My code works smoothly now!

Comment: But why you wanna do this? I think the List implementations given in Java are really sophisticated. What kind of functionallity you need which is not provided by the given Classes.

Comment: @ChristianSchack I want to use a Comparator, because my PersonList has individual Person Objects.My Person Objects have a lot of parameters and I need to be able to compare all the parameters using LinkedLists.

Comment: yeah thats why the equals Method exists, which is implicitly used by the List implementations. So you have just to overload the equals function of type of your list entry to achive the expected comparision

Comment: Not sure I follow... you can write your own `Comparator` on a `LinkedList` (say), without having to extend it and add methods.  It would be different if you wanted your list to implement `Comparable<PersonList>`.  Maybe I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ChristianSchack if he says he wants `Comparator`, that implies that he wants some sort of ordering relationship, not just `equals`.

Comment: @All In this case his Person class must implement toCompare Methode the Comparable interface in the way he wants and use the Standard JDK Collections.sort(<object of type List>, Comparator> method.

Comment: As i already said. for me it makes completely no sense to implement an own List class. Every extension which must be made is possible using given enxtension points or interfaces.

Comment: @ajb How would I go about writing my own Comparator for a Linked List? Thanks so much, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to `implement` the built in interface [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). It would need to define all the methods listed in the interface `java.util.List`.

Comment: Although i think that this answer is correct, yes it is indeed, i think that it leads to completely wrong software development behaviour, because there are mechanism to extend the List behaviour with standard JDK classes (Comparable, equals() method) which are tested and proofed since a couple of years.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. I was just trying to answer the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to overload the equals function which is implemented by every
class of Type Object (Every class). The list implementation will use your equals implementation due to the polymorphic concept of OOP.
I strongly recommend to use the given List implemenmtations because they meet all
performance issues you don't even think about. When you have concurrency issues refer to the documentation.

In order to achieve customized comparison you have to implement the Comparable interface
and implement its method toCompare(..);

In this way you can use all given Collection API classes and extend them using your own
comparison or equals algorithm which meets your application needs.

Update to to Comments

```
class Person implements Compareable {

  @override
  public int compareTo(Person p) {
    return p.age > this.age; //Or whatever
 }


   @Override
   equals(Object person) {
   if (person instanceof Person) {

     Person p = (Person)person;
     if (p.x == this.x &&
        p.y == this.y &&
        p.address.equals(this.address) {
        ...
        return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And now just intialize you list.

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
or
List<Persin> personList = new Vector<Person>();
or
LinkedList<Person> personList = new Queue<Person>();

and and and.

Collections.sort(personList);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is really useful- however, I need to be able to sort the parameters of my Person object stored in the List alphabetically and numerically, depending on the parameter being compared. So I couldn't just use the equals method, but instead something that would compare/sort it.

Comment: Yes thats why i updated my example with the Comparable Iinterface which needs to be implemented by your Person class. You can implement your own comparison within the toCompare method and than pass  your List to the Collections.sort() method which is provided by standard SDK

Comment: In my oppionion it is a mess to implement it all from scratch either way it is interesting doin that ;-)

Comment: You can do even more. You are able to provide a complete Comparator class to the Collections.sort() method. Just have a look. There are many nice Tutorials doin that. I think it meets your requirements. If not i am really interested in your code. Hope i could help!

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your idea now! It makes a lot more sense! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: It was me a pleasure if it was usefull. Just an advice mostly there exist already Solutions for the main Problems. The Problem is how to explain the google search entry to find that solution. And @nichi this problem i have also the whole day so pls don't take at it as a critiscm just take it as an advice to be faster than the others.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the comment, "How would I go about writing my own Comparator for a Linked List?":

```
public class PersonListComparator implements Comparator<LinkedList> {
    @Override
    public int compare(LinkedList list1, LinkedList list2) {
        // something that returns a negative value if list1<list2, 0 if list1 and
        // list2 are equal, a positive value if list1>list2.
    }
}
```

See the javadoc for [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), especially the text at the top.  This explains what could happen if the `compare` function could return 0 when `list1.Equals(list2)` is false.  It's not necessarily a problem, depending on how you use it.

Note that I'm still assuming you want to compare entire lists (rather than just individual `Person`s).  Based on later comments, it looks like you want to compare `Person` objects, but provide different ways to compare ("depending on the different parameter being compared").  You could define more than one class that implements `Comparator<Person>`.  Or you could define a class that takes a parameter when you construct the object:

```
public enum ComparisonType { NAME, AGE, WEIGHT } // whatever

public class ComparePerson implements Comparator<Person> {
    private ComparisonType type;
    public ComparePerson(ComparisonType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        switch(type) {
        case NAME:
            // return comparison based on the names
        case AGE: 
            // and so on
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, so I could have made a mistake, but you get the idea.  Hope this helps, but it's still possible I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.